# How to convert div elements into jpeg format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to convert div elements into image format( jpg,png) . Inside this div contains lot of div's li elements etc..  I tried to convert it using html2canvas() function. But I cant save it in jpg format.

```
 html2canvas($("#acceptDrop"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var image1 = new Image();
        image1 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        document.getElementById("imageId").setAttribute("src", image1);
    }
});
$("#imagemodal").show();
```

But this is not working according to my need. So could anyone help me to find a solution?

Comment: Create a fiddle, html2canvas is proven to work with elements that don't have resources from remote domains.

Comment: @AdamAzad, __from `cross-domain` to be specific__

Comment: I got image src like this,      <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABJ4AAANcCAYAAAAelGXbAAAgAElEQVR4XuzdCXwV1fn..==" id="imageId">